# What is the context of the quote “Sue, use your legs” - Stewie

Tags: dialogue, family-guy

­Breanna Stewart wore a T-shirt at the [Seattle Storm victory parade](https://www.king5.com/article/sports/wnba/storm/wnba-champion-seattle-storm-reign-supreme-at-victory-parade-rally/281-593620393) which read:

> “Sue, use your legs” - Stewie

Breanna is know as Stewie and Sue Bird is another player on the team. I know the T-shirt is also a reference to the TV show *Family Guy*.

What is the context of the quote on the show?

Comment: How do you know the shirt is a reference to family guy?

Comment: Hey Ben your link is broken - I can't access it from here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sue Bird's teammate Breanna "Stewie" Stewart used that line in [this article](https://www.theplayerstribune.com/en-us/articles/sue-bird-seattle-storm):

> Stewie fixed my shot. Alright, so you know how I said that Stewie
>   hasn’t gotten enough credit for Game 5? Well most of that is because
>   of what I already talked about: 28 and 7, 11 for 21 from the field,
>   refusing to let Phoenix run away with it early, pretty much anchoring
>   us in every way. But what I also want people to know is that, my
>   flurry of jumpers there, in crunch time — Stewie really deserves
>   credit for those as well. I started the game shooting alright, but for
>   some reason went cold around the second quarter. **And it was Stewie who
>   came up to me, while I was on the bench in the third, and she said,
>   “Gotta use your legs more, gotta use your legs more.” And I’m like,
>   “Huh?” And Stewie looks at me and she’s like, “Your shot. It’s short.
>   Gotta use your legs more.”**

The T-shirt simply mixes two contexts.